# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'staff' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Tags: php, html, mysql

I modified my code and this error doesn't seem to go no matter what

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('feedback', $con); 

isset($_REQUEST['submit']);  

$sql="INSERT INTO feedback ( 1Staff, 1subject, 1Rate1, 1Rate2, 1Rate3, 1Rate4, 1Rate5, 2Staff, 2subject, 2Rate1, 2Rate2, 2Rate3, 2Rate4, 2Rate5, 3Staff, 3subject, 3Rate1, 3Rate2, 3Rate3, 3Rate4, 3Rate5, 4Staff, 4subject, 4Rate1, 4Rate2, 4Rate3, 4Rate4, 4Rate5, 5Staff, 5subject, 5Rate1, 5Rate2, 5Rate3, 5Rate4, 5Rate5)
VALUES
('$_POST[1staff]','$_POST[1subject]','$_POST[1Rate1]','$_POST[1Rate2]','$_POST[1Rate3]','$_POST[1Rate4]','$_POST[1Rate5]','$_POST[2staff]','$_POST[2subject]','$_POST[2Rate1]','$_POST[2Rate2]','$_POST[2Rate3]','$_POST[2Rate4]','$_POST[2Rate5]','$_POST[3staff]','$_POST[3subject]','$_POST[3Rate1]','$_POST[3Rate2]','$_POST[3Rate3]','$_POST[3Rate4]','$_POST[3Rate5]','$_POST[4staff]','$_POST[4subject]','$_POST[4Rate1]','$_POST[4Rate2]','$_POST[4Rate3]','$_POST[4Rate4]','$_POST[4Rate5]','$_POST[5staff]','$_POST[5subject]','$_POST[5Rate1]','$_POST[5Rate2]','$_POST[5Rate3]','$_POST[5Rate4]','$_POST[5Rate5]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  echo $values;

mysql_close($con);
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thankyou.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

('$_POST[1staff]','$_POST[1subject]'.... being line 17
I tried everything and this is driving me carzy

Comment: Array keys in strings need quoting too. And your code is vulnerable to SQL injection: google it, change it.

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs proper escaping ...

You have used it like..

```
'$_POST[1Rate5]','$_POST[2staff]','$_POST[2subject]',
```

You have modify them like this..

```
".$_POST['1Rate5'].",".$_POST['2staff'].",".$_POST['2subject'].",
^-- Add a double quote         ^-- Add a single quote around  ^-- Make use of concatenate operator
```

You have to do this for all your other variables ....

Apart from these issues... The (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead,the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: `1staff`, etc, are just keys. Keys can be called whatever you like. The problem is a lack of error reporting, and the fact the keys aren't quoted

Comment: Thanks Shankar your suggestion works. I named it with a,b,c instead of 1,2,3 and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

If "1staff" and "1subject" are keys (as in, the value is $_POST['1staff']) then, $_POST vars can be concatenated.

```
"...('". $_POST['1staff'] ."..."
```

and likewise for the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ('{$_POST["1stuff"]}','{$_POST["1stuff"]}',)